# how to edit wp-login action whenever if a user puts on hold?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I have written a functionality like super admin can put user accounts on "hold". I have to make sure the user account which put his account on hold unable to login. The problem here is the user is able to login if still his account is on hold. I am using a 'custom user meta' field called 'holdUser' while super admin put a user on hold. While user login I am using the wordpress's wp-login action, how to edit wp-login action so that a user cannot login based on a custom user meta field in wordpress. While user account is put on hold I am updating the 'user meta' like below:

```
if(isset($_GET['user_id']) && ($_GET['action']=='hold'))
{
  update_user_meta( $_GET['user_id'], 'holdUser',1 );
  wp_mail($email_to, $subject, $content,$headers);
}
```

My Login form has the following code:

```
<form method="post" action="'.$this->SiteUrl.'wp-login.php">
  <input type="text" id="user_login" name="log">
  <input type="password" name="pwd">
  <button target="" class="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

My Question here is how to edit 'wp-login.php' hook based on a user_meta field 'holdUser' if its value is 1 then not to login that user.?

Comment: your code `if(isset($_GET['user_id']) && ($_GET['action']=='hold'))` is working??

Answer (score 0):

**From Admin :**

go to the Users dashboard panel and change the user's role to "
-- No role for this site --"

**Use plugin for that:**

https://9seeds.com/2013/08/26/how-to-disable-wordpress-user-accounts/

You can check like this.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    //The user has the "author" role
}
```

Comment: First, Thanks for your quick reply. I am using the "Role Manager" plugin for all the user roles. I understood your solution a bit only but I am not sure how to do it?

Comment: Then just create new role and check it inside the hook. wp_login

Comment: @prasadchinthala Please provide your plugin link which is currently inuse

Comment: I have created a new user role called 'no-role' by using "Role Manager" plugin(as I was already using this plugin) whenever user account put on hold I am changing that user role to 'no-role'. but a new problem got arised here that is: 'Super Admin' is unable to see that user account from the users list again if he want to 'unhold' it. Role Manager plugin link http://www.im-web-gefunden.de/index.html but the plugin site is closed now, it is developed by Thomas Schneider.

Comment: then you have to find an alternative plugin.If author  support not there.Can I download that plugin?

Comment: If its possible share plugin at vasimmca007atgmail.com

Comment: I have sent you plugin, please check your Email once.

Answer (score 0):

try putting word `true` at the place of `1`

```
  update_user_meta( $_GET['user_id'], 'holdUser', true );
```

Comment: First, Thanks for the quick reply. I tried putting 'true' value for 'holdUser' user_meta of an already on hold user by directly updating the database in PhpMyAdmin. But no luck its not working.

Comment: Can u try this one?
[New User Approve](https://mr.wordpress.org/plugins/new-user-approve/)
I guess u can access ur code from this plugin.

Comment: @Rasika you are right but he needs to be add just one hook there

Comment: @Rasika Yes as Vasim Vanzara told, I want it to do by coding like just adding one line of code whenever user account is putting on hold. Is there any way of like setting 'user_status' field to 1 or 0 as wordpress 'wp_users' table has different user fields.

Comment: I found this example on php.net. where values are assigned
<?php 
  $user_id = 9;
  $key = 'last_name';
  $single = true;
  $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
  echo '<p>The '. $key . ' value for user id ' . $user_id . ' is: ' . $user_last . '</p>'; 
?>

See if this can help u in case

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from "wordpress.stackexchange" this is the link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247729/how-to-restrict-user-login-whenever-if-a-user-puts-on-hold-by-editing-wp-login-a